# Can't get my Batch Script to work due to incorrect coding or bugs

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to manipulate a simple data series set (input data) as listed below to get an output csv file as shown below.  I have been pulling my hair out trying to work out where the bugs are and how to code this script, but could not work it out.

I can't get my simple batch script to work, when I run the batch program it does nothing.  Here is the code I'm using, the input data I'm using, and the output data that I need to obtain:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=1-7* delims=," %%A IN (eurusd1.csv) DO (
    set sum1 = %%~D - %%~E
    set /a result=(sum!*1000000)+1
    echo %%~A,%%~B,%%~C,%%~D,%%~E,%%~F,!result!
) >> output.csv
```

Input data:

> ```
> 2020.12.24,16:44,1.21906,1.21909,1.21897,1.21905,1
> 2020.12.24,16:45,1.21904,1.21910,1.21889,1.21906,1
> 2020.12.24,16:46,1.21905,1.21913,1.21899,1.21909,1
> ```

Want output data to look like this:

> ```
> 2020.12.24,16:44,1.21906,1.21909,1.21897,1.21905,120
> 2020.12.24,16:45,1.21904,1.21910,1.21889,1.21906,211
> 2020.12.24,16:46,1.21905,1.21913,1.21899,1.21909,141
> ```

Comment: `set sum1 =` will define a variable named `sum1<space>` not `sum1`, and `set /a` will only work with 32-bit signed integers, not floating point numbers. Also when using delayed expansion, the variable would be expanded using `!sum1!`, not `sum!`, although that is not needed because when using `set /a`, standard variables are expanded automatically, so there's no need to enclose them with `!` or `%` characters at all. I would advise that you perform this task using a different scripting language, perhaps Windows Scripting Host, or PowerShell, which can both perform your arithmetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.
SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q65529783.csv"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.csv"

(
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1-7delims=," %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1-4delims=." %%s IN ("%%d.%%e") DO SET /a value=(%%s*100000^)+1%%t-(%%u*100000^)-1%%v&SET /a value=10*value+1
 ECHO %%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f,!value!
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q65529783.csv` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as `%outfile%`

The `usebackq` option is only required because I chose to add quotes around the source filename.

First, read and tokenise using `,` - 7 columns, so tokens 1-7, although the last is unused.

Next, re-tokenise the string `%%d.%%e` using `.` as a delimiter. Note the dot between `%%d` and `%%e`.

Now set our value. Since there is no indication of the value-ranges involved (I have assumed that they are all positive) then we convert `%%d` to a six-digit number by multiplying `%%s` by 100000 and adding `1%%t` to that. This takes care of the situation where `%%t` contains a leading 0 which would otherwise be treated as octal.

Rinse and repeat for `%%e` and perform the subtraction, noting that the `1` preceding `%%v` balances that preceding `%%t`. The carets are required so that `cmd` sees the `)` as part of the `set`, not the `for`.

Since the result is now 10000* the floating-point difference, multiply by 10 and add 1, as anticipated in the original code.

and output the result.

Since you don't explain why the first result of the manipulation is `120`, which seems illogical given the formula, I'll assume that this is an error and it should be `121`.

Comment: Magoo, I have edited my answer to show that my output matches that requested in the question. That means your assumption of an error, and that `120` should read `121` may not be correct in this instance.

Comment: @Compo : yes, I saw that. Please explain how the formula `set /a result=(sum!*1000000)+1` (given the syntax error  is corrected and we have a `cmd` working with floating-point) can possibly end with any character other than `1` if the FP number in question has 5 decimal places, `WSH`'s opinion notwithstanding O.o

Comment: TBF, you could say I cheated a little, because technically the results from `Eval(((WScript.Arguments(0)-WScript.Arguments(1))*1000000)+1)` for the three records posted, read as, `120.999999999898`, `211.000000000043`, and `141.000000000029`. Now I could have chosen to just `Round` it, which would have been `Round(Eval(((WScript.Arguments(0)-WScript.Arguments(1))*1000000)+1),0)`, or more correctly perform the math, `Eval((WScript.Arguments(0)*1000000)-(WScript.Arguments(1)*1000000)+1)`, but decided to just take the Integer part, to prove my point. We do not really know what the task requires.

Comment: Thanks Magoo and Compo for your great solutions.  Your codes work great.  You were correct in picking up my error, in the output data the value 120 was supposed to read 121.  Thanks again.  Really appreciate your help.  Regards, Rodney

Answer (score 0):

In order to remain on topic, here's a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) example which uses the built-in Windows Scripting Host, to perform the floating point arithmetic for you.

```batch-file
<!-- :
@SetLocal EnableExtensions
@If Exist "eurusd1.csv" ((For /F UseBackQTokens^=1-6Delims^=^,EOL^= %%G In (
            "eurusd1.csv")Do @For /F %%M In (
            '%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe //NoLogo "%~f0?.wsf" "%%J" "%%K"'
        )Do @Echo(%%G,%%H,%%I,%%J,%%K,%%L,%%M)>"output.csv")
@Exit /B
-->
<Job><Script Language="VBScript">
WScript.Echo Int(Eval(((WScript.Arguments(0)-WScript.Arguments(1))*1000000)+1))
</Script></Job>
```

Despite your wanted record one, field seven, value seeming wrong when I read your question, this is the result I have just achieved when testing the above script against your posted source CSV content:

```
2020.12.24,16:44,1.21906,1.21909,1.21897,1.21905,120
2020.12.24,16:45,1.21904,1.21910,1.21889,1.21906,211
2020.12.24,16:46,1.21905,1.21913,1.21899,1.21909,141
```

Of course, if you didn't really want the math performing by rounding down to an integer, you should change the WSH line to either:

```batch-file
WScript.Echo Eval((WScript.Arguments(0)*1000000)-(WScript.Arguments(1)*1000000)+1)
```

or

```batch-file
WScript.Echo Round(Eval(((WScript.Arguments(0)-WScript.Arguments(1))*1000000)+1),0)
```

which should produce a result like this:

```
2020.12.24,16:44,1.21906,1.21909,1.21897,1.21905,121
2020.12.24,16:45,1.21904,1.21910,1.21889,1.21906,211
2020.12.24,16:46,1.21905,1.21913,1.21899,1.21909,141
```